# Is 2 GB and 4 GB of RAM installed possible?

Tags: memory, motherboard

My motherboard has 2 slots of RAM. Is it possible for a 2 GB and 4 GB installed? will the computer show 6 GB usable? windows 7 64 bit, ddr3. thank you mates.

Comment: What is your motherboard?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It is possible. You will have 6GB usable.

(No broad answer because there are several identical and well answered questions here on [SU]).